# How to get my app listed on the people's hub as a contact app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

For Windows Phone 8 I have created and published an [app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/local-only-contact-store/7ef22acc-82cd-4cab-b3ef-6524633e2f52) which creates a local-only address book (no automatic synchronization to the cloud with no data access for other apps installed on the phone) and by chance I discovered today that the system lists some apps that are capable of storing contacts in the people's hub (see screenshot). How can I achieve to get my app listed there?

[image: Adding a contacts app under Windows Phone 8]

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone 8.1 there are two main options (in open API) for implementation of the contacts application on the Smartphone.

It all depends on your scenario.
I think you need to learn starting from here:
[Implementing contact bindings in a Windows Phone 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642083(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Is it correct that I need to add `<Extension ExtensionName="People_Connect_Manual" ConsumerID="{bedab396-3404-490c-822e-13309c687e97}" TaskID="_default" />` to the WMAppManifest.xml in order to achieve what I described in my question? What Guid should I put as ConsumerID?